# Can one's PhD work be an extension of their Masters research?

Tags: phd, masters, thesis

I am currently pursuing a Masters degree in Literature, and I see potential in further research on the current topic of my dissertation for a PhD in the future. I have been told that an Honours thesis cannot be used as a foundation for a Masters dissertation, so i am wondering if a Masters dissertation can be used as a base for a PhD dissertation later on.

Comment: Sorry?  Why _can't_ an honours thesis be used as the foundation for a master's dissertation?

Answer (score 8):

Seeing your question, I guess this can vary from field to field, but the practice I've seen (engineering, neuroscience, and psychology) is that the PhD work *often* is an extension of the masters research. The masters work explores one facet of the research problem, and the PhD thesis explores two or three more. This is often a practical matter, as sometimes the masters is one step towards the eventual granting of a PhD.

Answer (score 7):

What defines a PhD dissertation can change from one field to another, from one university to another. However, in my case, one chapter of my PhD thesis corresponds to a condensed version of my Master thesis, and as far as I can tell, it's not an unusual practice from where I come from (computer science, france).

It makes sense when the PhD is somehow an extension of the Master thesis, that is, the Master thesis is used to study a particular aspect of the PhD research problem. That being said, the better for you is probably to check some PhD dissertations coming from your department, and check the intersection with the corresponding Master thesis.

Answer (score 1):

In general the master's thesis and the doctoral thesis should not be on exactly the same topic. On the other hand, it is entirely rational for earlier theses to provide the inspiration for later work in one's career.

What you can't really do is retread the same ground—you will need to develop a different topic, with different literature citations and original research. But the move doesn't have to be radical—in literature, for instance, you don't have to go from Sophocles to Virginia Woolf. But you probably shouldn't do *The Winter's Tale* for your master's thesis and then *Cymbeline* for your PhD thesis, either.

Comment: Why not?  As long as the PhD thesis contributes enough new ideas/results, why does it matter whether it's on _exactly_ the same topic as the MS thesis?

Comment: It can be done, but you do run the risk of boxing yourself in.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of any institution imposing a restriction such that your doctoral research is in a different field to your Master's research.

As long as your PhD research is a significant body of original research that greatly extends your Master's experience and appropriately cites any previous findings, there should not be a problem.

Indeed, in some countries it is possible to *convert* your Master's research into a PhD. For instance, if you are 6 months into a project and decide you want to greatly extend the scope of your research, you may be allowed a conversion. Bear in mind that where I live, a Master's degree is not a requirement to begin a PhD (you only need an honours degree, which is 1 year of postgraduate lectures and a small research project).